# What Is The Best Keystore to use?

Tags: java, groovy

I want to use [Keystore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystore) in my upcoming project. I saw that there is an [Keystore API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) in Java. But that seems to be very complicated.

Are there any other good keystore available that work well with Java/Groovy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of.  From my perspective, the API is relatively as minimal as possible give the things that it needs to supply.

```
KeyStore keyStore = keyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load( inputStream, storePassword.getBytes() );

// Get a key
if ( keyStore.isKeyEntry(alias) ) {
   Key key = keyStore.getKey(alias, keyPassword.getBytes());
}

// Store a new key
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
KeySpec keySpec ...; // depends on what kind of key you want to create (ie. rsa, etc..)
Key key = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
// sign the key here
Certificate certChain[] = ...; // get the cert chain
keyStore.setKeyEntry(newAlias, newKey, newKeyPassword.getBytes(), certChain);
keyStore.store(outputStream, storePassword.getBytes());
```

This is relatively minimal code to handle what a keystore needs to do.